# Авто сохранение в Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sql-server

Создал класс модели:

```
public class MainModel
{
  MagnesiumEntites _context;
  public Mainmodel()
  {
    _context = new MagnesiumEntites();
    _Parts = new ObservableCollection<Part>(_context.part);
  }

  private ObservableCollection<Part> _Parts;
  public ObservableCollection<Part> Parts
  {
    get { return _Parts; }
    set { value = _Parts; } 
  }
}
```

И привязал к DataGrid коллекцию Parts. Как мне при изменении в таблице сохранять изменения сразу в базу ?

Answer (score 1):

У `ObservableCollection` есть событие `CollectionChanged`.

В обработчике события вызывайте `_context.SaveChanges()`